# How can I create data structure with list of key, value pair?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap

I have below data as input, looking to create a data structure as below.

Input:

```
Key,type,alias

Aggregator_aggregator_se,Sorter,So_so
Aggregator_aggregator_se,Sorter,So_so
Aggregator_aggregator_se,Sorter,So_so
Expression_expr_se,Aggregator,Ag_ag
Expression_expr_se,Aggregator,Ag_ag
Expression_expr_se,Aggregator,Ag_ag
Expression_expr_se,Aggregator,Ag_ag
Expression_expr_se,Aggregator,Ag_ag
Expression_expr_se,Sorter,So_so
Expression_expr_se,Sorter,So_so
Expression_expr_se,Aggregator,Ag_ag
Expression_expr_se,Aggregator,Ag_ag
Filter_filter_se,Expression,Ex_ex
Filter_filter_se,Expression,Ex_ex
Filter_filter_se,Expression,Ex_ex
Filter_filter_se,Expression,Ex_ex
Filter_filter_se,Expression,Ex_ex
```

Output:

```
{ 'Aggregator_aggregator_se' : [ {type:  'Sorter', count: 3, value: 'So_so'], 

'Expression_expr_se' : [ {type:  'Aggregator', count: 7, value: 'Ag_ag'}, {type:  'Sorter', count: 2, value: 'So_so'}],

'Filter_filter_se' : [ {type:  'Expression', count: 5,value: 'Ex_ex']
}
```

How should I achive this data structure?
I am very new to python so need some help.

Comment: That's not a valid Python data structure. It _looks_ like a dictionary but your keys are not strings. I suggest you to follow an introductory Python tutorial before you attempt to write anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import csv

out = {}
with open("your_data_file.txt") as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    # skip header
    next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        # skip empty lines
        if not line:
            continue
        key, type_, value = line
        out.setdefault(key, {}).setdefault(type_, {}).setdefault(value, 0)
        out[key][type_][value] += 1


out = {
    k: [
        {"type": kk, "count": vvv, "value": kkk}
        for kk, vv in v.items()
        for kkk, vvv in vv.items()
    ]
    for k, v in out.items()
}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "Aggregator_aggregator_se": [
        {"type": "Sorter", "count": 3, "value": "So_so"}
    ],
    "Expression_expr_se": [
        {"type": "Aggregator", "count": 7, "value": "Ag_ag"},
        {"type": "Sorter", "count": 2, "value": "So_so"},
    ],
    "Filter_filter_se": [{"type": "Expression", "count": 5, "value": "Ex_ex"}],
}
```

Comment: This works so good!! thank you so much. Actually the previous questions output is what I want to achieve ultimately. will combine both of this programs. Thanks again! you are great

Comment: is there anyway I can reach out to you if I have any python related questions? or I can tag you if I need help?